# How to install ngx-bootstrap to my angular 4 project

Tags: angular, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I may not be able to install ngx-bootstrap to my angular 4 project and hence not able to use the predefined templates. I had gone through below two links for ngx-bootstrap installation, please guide me the right way to do it.

https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started

https://loiane.com/2017/08/how-to-add-bootstrap-to-an-angular-cli-project/

Answer (score 5):

`ngx-bootstrap` contains all core (and not only) Bootstrap components powered by Angular. So you don't need to include original JS components, but we are using markup and css provided by Bootstrap.

**Installation instructions**

Check out their official [Getting Started](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap#getting-started) Page on Github.

Controls and Documentation is [available here](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/getting-started).

**Install ngx-bootstrap from npm:**

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

Add needed package to NgModule imports:

```
import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';

@NgModule({
  ...
  imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot(),...]
  ...
})
```

**Add component to your page:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
        tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
  Simple demo
</button>
```

You will need bootstrap styles:

**Bootstrap 3**

```
<!-- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

**Bootstrap 4**

```
<!--- index.html -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Comment: do i have to install it into my project directory or I have to install it globally

Comment: If you are going to re-use the same library in a bunch of different projects you can install it `-g` globally. Otherwise you can install it only on your project location.

Comment: You can read more about this [here](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/).

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap --save
```

And it's given there:

[image]

Comment: do I have to install this inside my project directory or I have to install it globally

Comment: At the same directory location where you run your ng serve command

Comment: Any idea how to install v7.0.0